# Finding the library an imported function is from in IDA

Tags: ida, elf, shared-object

I'm fairly new to reversing, and I have even less experience with IDA Pro. I am wondering if there is a way to figure out from where an imported function is imported, i.e. a memory location I can find with ldd or even better a .so name.

Answer (score 5):

When I had the same problem (I was working on ELF binaries from Linux and QNX systems) I had to do the following:

- run `ldd` on the executable to get the list of loaded libraries
- obtain a list of exports of each mentioned library (by running `nm -CD full_library_name | grep " T "` on the system)
- If your function is there - it is there
- If you are working with C++, take demangling into consideration

If you don't have an ability to use shell on your system, you can automate getting list of exports using IDAPython ( `idautils.Entries()` ) and [-S ida command line option](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/417.shtml).

If the library is loaded dynamically (by using `dlopen/dlsym` for example) you'll have to find corresponding `dlopen` call and find out its arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Created this plugin recently, you can use https://github.com/0xMirasio/AutoResolv. This is an IDA plugins for resolving imports and show the library origin. You can also refactor code by importing function signature from the libs.

Comment: Welcome to RE.SE. It is customary to disclose one's affiliation with a recommendation. In this case you seem to be the owner of the repo, right? Note: there's _nothing_ wrong with promoting a solution you created, but it's good style to say that you are the one who made it _when_ you are promoting it (also holds for noncommercial offerings like yours). Thanks.

Comment: Ok , going to edit